# Read Multi Dimension Array in PHP

Tags: php

how to read "test" in "dir"?

```
$_USERS = array (
      10 => array (
                   `name` => `xyz`,
                   `role` => `user`,
                   `dir`  => `["test","test1"]`,),
                   );
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `echo $_USERS['10']['dir'][0];`

Comment: echo $_USERS['10']['dir'][0]; is not working, it show only letter. I want to read test

Comment: If it only shows one letter than that is not your array. Post the real array. Or is `["test","test1"]` a string?

Comment: @ankur tiwari , I want to read dir array like test, test1

Comment: @Andreas  How to read dir if it is not array. Any suggestions will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are creating this array statically in your script, I would advise against using the ` quotation. Instead use a single or double quotation.

The below example works the way I believe you are requesting:

```
$_USERS = array (
  10 => array (
               "name" => 'xyz',
               "role" => 'user',
               "dir"  => '["test","test1"]',),
               );

echo json_decode($_USERS[10]["dir"])[0];
```

Because the array in "dir" is not a real array, we can translate it into a PHP array by using json_decode.

Comment: Great this is what I want. Thank you very much @james

Comment: You are very welcome. Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer :)